# Check if path is absolute or relative

Tags: files-and-directories

How can I check if a filesystem path is absolute or relative in a cross-platform way?

For my purposes, I consider a path absolute if points to a location that is independent of `Directory[]`.

I only need to check paths valid on the current operating system. I never need to check Windows paths on Unix or vice versa.

---

Examples of absolute paths on Unix:

- `/foo/bar`
- `~/baz` (This is sometimes considered relative as it is user `$UserName`-dependent.  However, it is not `Directory[]`-dependent.)

On Windows:

- `F:\foo\bar`
- `F:/foo/bar`

Relative paths on Unix:

- `foo/bar`
- `.`, `./foo`, `..`

Relative paths on Windows:

- `foo\bar`
- `.`, `.\bar`, `..`, etc.
- `\foo\bar` (May be either of `C:\` or `D:\`, etc.)
- any of the above with a `/` separator instead of `\`

These are just a few examples. I may have missed several special cases. I am looking for something which always works and preferably doesn't depend on my own partial understanding of what forms an absolute or relative path may take on different OSs. I would rather not start matching strings, at least not without a reference document which gives an exhaustive list of all possible path syntaxes both for absolute and relative paths.

The ideal solution would use a feature that asks the operating system directly:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773660(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 8):

The only reliable way I found so far was by using Java through J/Link:

```
Needs["JLink`"]

Clear[absolutePathQ]
absolutePathQ[File[path_String]] := absolutePathQ[path]
absolutePathQ[path_String] :=
 Module[{file},
   InstallJava[];
   JavaBlock[
     file = JavaNew["java.io.File", path];
     file@isAbsolute[]
   ]
 ]
```

---

My best pure Mathematica attempt was the following:

```
Clear[absolutePathQ]
absolutePathQ[path_] := ExpandFileName[path] === FileNameJoin@FileNameSplit[path]
```

As @george2079 points out, this fails on absolute paths like `/var/../bin/sh`.

---

Neither of these two methods consider `~` absolute.  That is not unreasonable and not really a problem. This case is special enough that I can always check `StringStartsQ[path, "~"]`.

Comment: this will break on liunx if you have `.` or `..` embedded in an absolute path, eg `/var/../bin/sh` gets cleaned up by `ExpandFileName` to `/bin/sh`

Comment: A possible alternative was comparing the name with its `AbsoluteFileName`, but it seems that it has issues with symlinks that `ExpandFileName` does not. Also, `ExpandFileName` and `FileNameSplit` work on `File`, so extracting the filename from them is redundant.

Comment: @rcollyer originally I had `ExpandFileName[path] === path`, so it wasn't redundant. Now it is.

Comment: Ah, I see. that would do it. :)